# Update .ButtonName on display of msoFileDialogFilePicker

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change the text of the "Open" button in msoFileDialogFilePicker to "Select".

The `.ButtonName` property should do this but the result is still "Open".

```
Dim str1, str2 as String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Title = "Select PO Report"
    .ButtonName = "Select"
    .InitialFileName = "C:\"
    .Filters.Add "Order File", "*.xls?", 1
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    str1 = Dir(.SelectedItems(1))
    str2 = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
```

Comment: I don't think it changes until you click on a file.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly it. I wish I could change it before the the file is selected.